# Multiple inclusion of header files leads to longer compile time?

Tags: c++, header-files, compile-time

Does including the same header files multiple times increase the compilation time?

For example, suppose every file in my project uses `<iostream>` `<string>` `<vector>` and `<algorithm>`. And if I include a lot of files in my source code, then does that increase the compile time?

I always thought that the guard headers served important purpose of avoiding double definitions but as a by product also eliminates double code.

Actually, someone I know proposed some ideas to remove such multiple inclusions. However, I consider them to be completely against the good design practices in c++. But was still wondering what might be the reasons of him to suggest the changes?

Comment: Of course, you should be sure that this is a real problem before expending a lot of effort to fix it. Modern compilers on modern systems take milliseconds to process `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<vector>`, and `<algorithm>`. This was a much bigger issue in the 1980's and early 1990's than it is now.

Comment: thanks for all your answers...
that was what i was thinking... i do not think the problem is serious enough to think about the policy he has suggested (basically he has suggested that we should not include a.hh in b.hh if b.hh already includes a c.hh which includes a.hh) i personally find it to be WRONG... especially if you are maintaining a BIG library...

Comment: @Jayesh Badwaik The *policy* your friend suggested is silly. If `b.hh` references types declared in `a.hh` it absolutely should include `a.hh` directly. Otherwise, tomorrow you may remove `c.hh`'s dependency on `a.hh`, and consequently delete its inclusion of that file, and your project won't compile anymore. The exception is that if `b.hh` can get away with forward declaring types in `a.hh` then you should do that instead of including the header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of these answers are wrong...  For modern compilers, there is *zero* overhead for including the same file multiple times, assuming the header uses the usual "include guard" idiom.

The GCC preprocessor, for example, has special code to [recognize the include guard idiom](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html).  It will not even open the header file (never mind reading it) for the second and subsequent `#include` directives.

I am not sure about other compilers, but I would be very surprised if most of them did not implement the same optimization.

Comment: According to a [Wikipedia article about `#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) the only compilers to do this are GCC and Clang. It does seem like a worthwhile feature that others could emulate.

Comment: Ah! Finally a sane voice in the noise!

Comment: By the way, even if such feature wasn't used, with header guards the only processing done to the included file is done by the preprocessor, the actual compiler doesn't see the "duplicated headers" at all - and the stages that take the most time are the parsing done by the compiler and the optimization, both avoided in this way.

Comment: How about in a project, foo1.h file includes <iostream>, foo2.h includes <iostream>. foo1.h and foo2.h do not include each other. Then the compiler compiles foo1.cpp and foo2.cpp. Does the compiler compile <iostream> two times?

Answer (score 1):

Another technique besides precompiled headers is the compiler firewall idiom, explained here:

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill04.htm

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm

Answer (score 1):

Every time `#include <something.h>` occurs in your source file, 'something.h' have to be found along the include path and read. But there is `#ifndef _SOMETHING_H_` check, so the content of such something.h would not be compiled.
Thus there is some overhead, but it is really small.

Answer (score 1):

If compile times were an issue, people used to use the optimisation recommended by Praetorian, originally recommened in [Large Scale Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620). However, most modern compilers automatically optimise for this case. For example, see [the help from gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_2.html#SEC9)

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use precompiled headers. I do not know which compiler you are using, but most of them have this feature. I suggest you to refer to your compiler-manual on how to achieve this.

It basically collects all headerfiles and compiles it into a object file which then can be used by the linker. That speeds up compiling very much.

Minor Drawback:

You need to have 1 "uberheader" which is included in every compilation-unit (.cpp).

In that uberheader, only include static headers from libraries, not your own. Then the compiler does not need to recompile it very often.

It helps esp. when using header-only libraries such as boost or glm, eigen etc.

HTH

Comment: Not all compilers support pre-compiled headers.

Comment: That's fine, but you just may want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: So you voted down because I said "most" and not "not all support it"? It is basically the same.... but well, I have to live with that.

Comment: I don't think "most" compilers support pre-compiled headers. In any event, you didn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, including the same header multiple times means that the file needs to be opened before the preprocessor guards kick in and prevent multiple definitions. The Mozilla source code uses the following trick to prevent this:

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

// whatever

#endif  /* FOO_H */
```

In all files that need to include foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#include "foo.h"
#endif
```

This prevents foo.h from having to be opened multiple times. Of course, this depends on everyone following a particular naming convention for their preprocessor guards.

You can't do this with standard headers, since there is no common naming convention for their preprocessor guards.

**EDIT:**
After reading your question again, I think you're asking about the same header being included in different source files. What I talked about above does not help with that. Each header file will still have to be opened and included at least once in every translation unit. The only way I know of to prevent this is to use precompiled headers, as *@scorcher24* mentioned in his answer. But I'd stay away from this solution, because there is no standard way of generating precompiled headers across compilers, unless the compile times are absolutely prohibitive.

Comment: Having include guards in foo.h is a good idea. But going the second step and adding them at the site of the inclusion is a really bad idea. Now you have to open foo.h and see what the include guard sentinel is, as it may not always be FOO_H. And then you have more chances for typos and maintenance problems when the filename changes. So, keep the internal include guards, but forget about external include guards.

Comment: @Brian Neal I agree that using the external guards makes your code fragile. I was just describing a trick I've seen elsewhere. I think it works for Mozilla because most of the headers that use this might be auto-generated for XPCOM using the XPIDL compiler.

Comment: @Brian Neal: SO takes out my username because I'm the owner of the post you're commenting on and I'm automatically notified of the comment :)

Comment: @Praetorian: Current compiler technology detects include guards, and the preprocessor will not even try to reopen the file after it has seen it. Basically when it processes file `a.h` it detects that if `A_HEADER` is defined there is nothing to do, when it reads a later `#include "a.h"` it checks whether `A_HEADER` is defined *before* opening the file. This is treated in [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.amazon.com/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586) item 24.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers, most notably Microsoft's, have a `#pragma once` directive that you can use to automatically skip an include file once it's already been included. This removes any performance penalty.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Comment: As is anything involving `#pragma`.

Comment: @Brian, I never said it wasn't. You may be able to put `#if` guards around it if your source is meant to be portable.

Comment: Actually, I don't know why `#pragma once` isn't standardized in some way... it is supported by almost any compiler, it solves the problem of non-uniform naming of include guards macros and macro clashes, and avoids adding extra logic to preprocessors to detect and optimize the include-guard idiom.

Comment: I don't think you can use #if guards around it because the text you #ifdef off is still required to be valid code. I found out this the hard way once.

Comment: @Brian, I think it depends on the compiler. Sure enough though, the compiler that doesn't understand the `#pragma` will also be the one that won't skip over it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue.  As others have said, **most** modern compilers
handle the case intelligently, and will only re-open the file in
degenerate cases.  Most is not all, however, and one of the major
exceptions is Microsoft, which a lot of people do have to support.  The
surest solution (if this is really a problem in your environment) is to
use the Lakos convention, putting the include guards around the
`#include` as well as in the header.  This means, of course, a standard
convention for generating the guard names.  (For external includes, wrap
them in your own header, which respects your local convention.)
Alternatively, you can use both the guards and `#pragma once`.  The
guards will always work, and most compilers will avoid the extra opens,
and `#pragma once` will usually avoid the extra opens with Microsoft.
(`#pragma once` cannot be implemented reliably in complex networked
situation, but as long as all of your files are on your local drive,
it's quite reliable.)